# How to convert factor to date in R without getting NA?

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I'm sorry I know this question has been asked thousand times, but I'm trying to convert my dates column which is in factor to date , but it gets NA !!

Here's my Data:

```
     'data.frame':  397774 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ ï..date      : Factor w/ 744 levels "2017-03-15","2017-03-16",..: 113 311 118 109 70 102 9 310 8 172 ...
     $ store        : int  43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 ...
     $ item         : int  43 295 296 295 43 43 43 296 296 43 ...
     $ qty          : int  61 73 145 255 267 242 200 121 48 182 ...
     $ unit_price   : num  10.1 13.3 11.9 13.3 10.1 ...
     $ item_category: int  13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 …
```

Here's my code:

```
     df$ï..date <- as.Date(
     paste0("-1",as.character(df$ï..date)), 
     format = "%b-%y-%d")
```

Here's what I get:

```
  'data.frame': 397774 obs. of  6 variables:
  $ ï..date      : Date, format: NA NA NA ...
  $ store        : int  43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 ...
  $ item         : int  43 295 296 295 43 43 43 296 296 43 ...
  $ qty          : int  61 73 145 255 267 242 200 121 48 182 ...
  $ unit_price   : num  10.1 13.3 11.9 13.3 10.1 ...
  $ item_category: int  13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 …
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why do you have the `paste("-1",...` part in there?

Comment: how do you want your dates to look like?

Comment: Your date format is obviously `"%Y-%m-%d"`. Why are you putting a `"-1"` in front?

Comment: Your dates look like they're in the default year-month-day format. Probably `f$ï..date <- as.Date(df$ï..date)` is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- the dates shown are not in the format of the format string shown.  They are in the format yyyy-mm-dd (or in terms of percent codes `%Y-%m-%d`), which is the default, so there is no need to specify any format at all
- the dates already have year, month and day so there is no need to paste anything onto them
- `as.Date` has a factor method. There is no need to convert them to character.

Try this:

```
x <- factor(c("2017-03-15","2017-03-16"))
as.Date(x)
## [1] "2017-03-15" "2017-03-16"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `NA` because your format is wrong

```
> as.Date("2017-03-15", format = "%b-%y-%d")
[1] NA
```

The `%Y` represents the year, `%m` the month and `%d` the day.

```
> as.Date("2017-03-15", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2017-03-15"
```